# Sum and Difference between odds and evens

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I manage to separate the odd and even numbers but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the odds with odds and even with evens and then subtract that to get the answer. i.e

(1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9) - (2 + 4 + 6 + 8) = 5

```
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
    sumDiff(numbers);
    
    function sumDiff(numbers) {
        let even = [];
        let odd = [];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
                even.push(numbers[i]);
            } // end 
            else {
                odd.push(numbers[i]);
            }// end else
            
        } //end of for loop
        
        console.log(odd);
        console.log(even);
    } // end of function
```

Now I don't want the full answer, but a nudge in the right direction. I figured I can separate the odd and even numbers first and then go from there.

Would I have to create a new function or could I still get it done within the same function?

Comment: why not just adding them as you find them? like, creating an oddTotal variable, an evenTotal variable, and add odds or evens as you find them

Comment: You can do a couple of things - you can loop over each array in a separate loop afterward and sum up the numbers in a new variable, you can use a reduce function, or you can sum up the numbers in the same spot you're adding them to the even and odd arrrays

Comment: Just start with `let sum = 0`, then add or subtract. Or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) where the example at the top is exactly what you need.

Comment: I recommend you look at the `filter` method available on all arrays. e.g. `['a', 'b','c'].filter(val => val !== 'a')` would give you `['b', 'c']`. You can use this technique first to get separate arrays of even and odd numbers.

Comment: Using ChrisG's first suggestion, you can do this in one simple loop with a test per number and either an addition or a subtraction.  Using [`Array.prorotype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can turn this into a readable one-liner.  So I'd suggest following that advice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, went with array.reduce and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, for the missing functionality you're looking for, you could use the [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to sum the values of the two arrays you created, like this:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
sumDiff(numbers);

function sumDiff(numbers) {
    let even = [];
    let odd = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(numbers[i]);
        } // end 
        else {
            odd.push(numbers[i]);
        }// end else

    } //end of for loop

    console.log(odd);
    console.log(even);
    
    let oddSum = odd.reduce((r, s) => r += s, 0)
    let oddEven = even.reduce((r, s) => r += s, 0)
    
    console.log("odd sum total: " + oddSum)
    console.log("even sum total: " + oddEven)
    console.log("difference: " + (oddSum - oddEven))
} // end of function
```